# Elegant solution to multiple select inputs?

Tags: html, forms, select, input

Multi-part problem here that's been bugging me for ages.  I'm somewhat of an amateur FYI and you can see the live site here:

http://artsparkcc.com/enroll.html

As you can see the site is an enrollment form for parents entering their kids in art classes.  It works fine but a lot of parents have been complaining that they would like to enroll in multiple classes at once.  Currently the form uses the CGI email script to email the form vars directly to the admins through a text file template.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a lightweight solution.  I've checked for some jquery multiple-select plugins but none of them work nice with my CGI email setup and I currently don't have the time to rewrite the whole page just for multiple selects.

Parents need to be able to enroll in as many or as few classes as possible, and the input result needs to be able to cleanly be sent to the admins for recording.  I thought about just making them all a big minefield of checkboxes but it looks ugly as sin and I'd like to keep the selects.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the jQuery plugin **[bsmSelect](https://github.com/vicb/bsmSelect)**?

Anyway, what is it about the "multiple-select" plugins that doesn't work nice with your CGI email setup?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I get home.  I figured if the script received more than one value with the same name it would just blow up.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add to the select tag the attribute `multiple="multiple"` you'll be able to select multiple classes. Your CGI script will recieve multiple values with the name Classchosen, you just have to make sure to parse them all.

Comment: Thank you.  Problem is that a bunch of soccer moms can't be asked to ctrl+click or shift+click anything.  I figured if the script received multiple values with the same name It'd just explode, do mind elaborating on what "parse them all" means?

Comment: @Tyler I would have to see how you normally handle your form inputs when the script gets them to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you Null Set, you are extremely awesome.  When the submit button is clicked a perl script is run that uses the template @ /emailtemplate.txt to email the form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the enrollment part of your form into two multi-select fields that transfer values from one to the other?

You can see a sample of what I mean [here](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html).

I think it'll make the interface easier to use (or maybe that's just me).